# Facebook C# SDK. How to automatic login user if they already login from facebook.com?

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Here's the problem,

I want to have the user auto login to my MVC3 website if they already login from facebook.com.

If they are not login from facebook.com, I will just simply show a login button and they can login by clicking on it as usual.

I cant seem to find a way to detect whether user had login from facebook.com unless I force the application to direct go into LoginUrl of Facebook, which is not good for user who was not logged in as this will prompt them a page where they have to login. I still want to allow guest access without facebook account.

Any idea? Thanks a million.

EDIT:

Sorry I forgot to mentioned the situation only apply to user who approve to use my app. Once they approve to use my app, I'll be able to detect their facebook login status.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: You can't. At least not without violating the facebook TOS and probably at least one or two laws.

**EDIT:** Your original question sounded like you wanted to try and hijack the facebook user session. What you are talking about here in the comments requires you to use facebook connect / facebook for websites.

You would want to start here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web

Comment: I've seen some site that actually able to do this such as http://shopsocial.ly/ . Once I approve to use their apps, everytime I go into that website they will detect whether I already logged into facebook.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. So does that mean I have to use their Javascript SDK instead of Facebook C# SDK that I'm using now?

Comment: I don't believe so, some quick googling I found this: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20with%20an%20ASP.NET%20MVC%203%20Website&referringTitle=Getting%20Started